# Uploading JSON file to MYSQL using Laravel not working

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am working on a script to upload a JSON file with all our COmpany data from our previous CRM system into a MYSQL database using laravel and i am running into an issue will parsing the json data. I have converted it to an array and run a foreach to upload each company, but it is throwing an error saying it cant convert from array to string. Im unsure what i am doing wrong here, my code is below as well as one company (all are very similar):

```
public function uploadCompanies()
{

    $json = File::get("database/data/accounts.json");
    $data = json_decode($json);

    foreach($data as $item) {

        DB::table('ucustomers')->insert(
            [
                'dynamics_guid'         => $item->accountid,
                'customer_code'         => $item->mc_unleashedcode,
                'customer_name'         => $item->name,
                'phone_number'          => $item->telephone1,
                'fax_number'            => $item->fax,
                'email'                 => $item->emailaddress1,
                'website'               => $item->websiteurl,
                'override_reps'         => [],

                'updated_at'            => date('Y-m-d H:i')

            ]
        );
    }

}
```

accounts.json

```
[
        {
            "@odata.etag": "W/\"145746454\"",
            "name": "Core Pharmacy",
            "opendeals": 0,
            "modifiedon": "2020-08-29T14:11:19Z",
            "address1_stateorprovince": "VIC",
            "telephone1": "03 9338 1504",
            "accountid": "5b46f158-d8ef-e911-a812-000d3a799888",
            "websiteurl": null,
            "mc_unleashedcode": "C1000096",
            "fax": "03 9334 5030"
            "emailaddress1": "tullamarine@locale.com.au",
        }
]
```

ERROR

```
 ErrorException 

  Array to string conversion

  at vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Str.php:488
    484| 
    485|         $result = array_shift($segments);
    486| 
    487|         foreach ($segments as $segment) {
  > 488|             $result .= (array_shift($replace) ?? $search).$segment;
    489|         }
    490| 
    491|         return $result;
    492|     }

      +8 vendor frames 
  9   app/Unleashed/DynamicsUpload.php:52
      Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::insert()

  10  app/Console/Commands/InsertDynamicsData.php:41
      App\Unleashed\DynamicsUpload::uploadCompanies()
```

Comment: I would highly recommend decouple the functionality into their own classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is. you try to assign array to string when insert:

```
public function uploadCompanies()
{

    $json = File::get("database/data/accounts.json");
    $data = json_decode($json);

    foreach($data as $item) {

        DB::table('ucustomers')->insert(
            [
                'dynamics_guid'         => $item->accountid,
                'customer_code'         => $item->mc_unleashedcode,
                'customer_name'         => $item->name,
                'phone_number'          => $item->telephone1,
                'fax_number'            => $item->fax,
                'email'                 => $item->emailaddress1,
                'website'               => $item->websiteurl,
                'override_reps'         => [], // error on this one

                'updated_at'            => date('Y-m-d H:i')

            ]
        );
    }

}
```

there are 2 solution to fixed it.

if you want to insert array to table direct you need to encode it like below:

```
public function uploadCompanies()
{

    $json = File::get("database/data/accounts.json");
    $data = json_decode($json);

    foreach($data as $item) {

        DB::table('ucustomers')->insert(
            [
                'dynamics_guid'         => $item->accountid,
                'customer_code'         => $item->mc_unleashedcode,
                'customer_name'         => $item->name,
                'phone_number'          => $item->telephone1,
                'fax_number'            => $item->fax,
                'email'                 => $item->emailaddress1,
                'website'               => $item->websiteurl,
                'override_reps'         => json_encode([]), // need to encode first

                'updated_at'            => date('Y-m-d H:i')

            ]
        );
    }

}
```

solution 2 is using model for create:

but first you need to cast override_reps field to array. so laravel will handle it for you

```
// assume you model name Customer
class Customer extends Model
{

    protected $casts =[
        'override_reps'=>'array',
    ];
}

// on controller

public function uploadCompanies()
{

    $json = File::get("database/data/accounts.json");
    $data = json_decode($json);

    foreach($data as $item) {

        Customer::create(
            [
                'dynamics_guid'         => $item->accountid,
                'customer_code'         => $item->mc_unleashedcode,
                'customer_name'         => $item->name,
                'phone_number'          => $item->telephone1,
                'fax_number'            => $item->fax,
                'email'                 => $item->emailaddress1,
                'website'               => $item->websiteurl,
                'override_reps'         => [],//lavavel model will encode it before insert

                'updated_at'            => date('Y-m-d H:i')

            ]
        );
    }

}
```

Comment: Thankyou im an idiot, it was the override_reps field, i cant insert an array (silly mistake) Thanks for pointing that out!